# How can I import a .txt file at specific URL into a PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, proxy, get

How can I import proxies definitions (in text format) as array from .txt file at the URL `http://domain.com/proxy.txt`?

This is the code:

(manual update)

```
$proxy_array = array("IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD",
"IP:PORT:USER:PASSWORD");
```

(Automatic update?)

```
$proxy_array = array("http://domain.com/proxy.txt");
```

Comment: Do you want to save the proxy related data in a text file and read them later again?

Comment: yes the proxy file updatet every day

Answer (score 2):

The [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function reads a file and creates an array with 1 entry for each line. You can also use it with URLs.

```
$proxy_array = file("http://domain.com/proxy.txt");
```

Comment: ...provided `allow_url_fopen` is enabled and PHP is not running in safe mode.